# How do I manage html font size so that it is parsed the same for iOS and Android

Tags: android, html, ios, parsing, nsattributedstring

So I have a small `html` snippet that is parsed to an `attributed string` in `iOS` and `Android`. In the `html` code the font size is set to 5 which looks good on `iOS` but is too big for `Android`. I believe this is due to font size in `html` being `px`, and `iOS` translates it to `pt` and `Android` to `dp`.

How do we get the same size on both devices? I have tried to resize the font after it has been `parsed`, both through code and in `storyboard` but it doesn't take. In code:

```
mystring.parseHtml()?.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.openSans(size: 17)], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: mystring.parseHtml()?.length ?? 0))
```

Is there anything that can be done with the `html` code to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be too opinionated, so take with a pinch of salt.

If you clamp your font-size around a relative width, you can save yourself a lot of work.

Once your font-size is set up, all your other sizes can be specified in `em` or `rem` sizes, so just adjusting your font makes everything else adjust relative to that.

You can introduce a simple media query to change the clamp for smaller / larger devices and have readable typography everywhere.

If you run the below snippet full screen and re-size your browser, you'll get a feel for how it works.

```css
body {
    font-size: clamp(16px, 5vw, 24px);
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In massa lacus, tincidunt a dolor in, aliquet finibus erat. Donec nec mauris non massa semper rutrum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ornare varius mauris, in tincidunt eros lobortis nec. Etiam ultricies, erat eu condimentum vehicula, urna sem dictum lectus, eget interdum augue dui vel tortor. Maecenas ornare iaculis iaculis. Cras porttitor pharetra malesuada. Ut venenatis magna pulvinar elit iaculis scelerisque sed quis mauris. Etiam mattis lectus a convallis congue. Donec scelerisque tempor nulla, sed luctus ante consectetur eget. Nunc porttitor semper feugiat. Morbi quis pretium odio. Quisque pulvinar dictum tellus, eget iaculis nisl aliquam at.</p>
<p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas viverra mauris vitae magna accumsan, in vestibulum ipsum sollicitudin. Sed ultrices, nisi ac fermentum aliquet, odio lectus aliquam ipsum, a rutrum nisl mi ut erat. Curabitur ut est accumsan, imperdiet tellus eget, mattis ante. Cras finibus ante in nisi bibendum, vitae malesuada velit efficitur. Sed pretium tortor eu leo blandit luctus. Aenean commodo blandit odio. Aliquam vel eros elit. Quisque pharetra erat ipsum, volutpat pellentesque nulla facilisis sed. Cras vel rhoncus turpis, non malesuada lorem. Nulla dictum pulvinar erat, nec consectetur urna tincidunt ac. Maecenas varius non turpis sed consectetur. Nullam a porta libero, id tempor orci.</p>
```